# Android - AsyncTask class in Activity class. Context crash the app

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-alertdialog, android-context

I'm creating AsyncTask class in Activity class. I need to get the Context in `AsyncTask` to build `AlertDialog`. I'm using constructor to point the context. My code:

```
public class Plan extends Activity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.plan);
           //// some Activity code....
    class fillSpiners extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    private Context context;    
    public fillSpiners(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
           AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            alert
            .setTitle("Title");
            /// setting up alert
            AlertDialog showAlert = alert.create();
            showAlert.show();

            String s;
            ///making s String stuff...
            return s;
        }
     } /// end of the AsyncTask class



/// now calling the fillSpiners method.
try {
    String a = new  fillSpiners(this).execute().get();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}
}
```

I've read about using constructor to give context to the alert dialog, but this code stops the app(crash). I think the context is problem here.

Comment: Sorry but can you post the whole code.. the above doesn't make sense..

Comment: Please post your logcat.

Comment: doInBackgorund-Allowed only background process show you have to load alertdialog in onPostExecute other way you have to showing alert dialog in **onPreExecute()** method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I know what is going on. I found this on stack overflow:

> The problem is 'You can show AlertDialogs from Activity only'. This is not an issue of context.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not passing context, context in your case is `null`. First create constructior for your async task inside of him. Wrote on fast.

```
fillSpiners(Context context)
{
   this.context = context;
}
```

Second run it:

```
new fullSpiners(Plan.this).execute(params);
```

Something like that;

Comment: still crash when I pass "context" to the alert dialog